# How do I use a shortened version of jQuery for a dropdown menu like this?

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I'm new in jQuery and still learning how to go about scripting the language. I recently tried to work on a dropdown menu but I feel like there's something that I'm doing wrong in the code, or more importantly, I feel like an expert in the language can write less lines of code than the ones I have. Can you please help me out. My Code looks like this:

HTML

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
    <li id="li_1"><a href="">PRODUCTS</a>
        <ul id="dropdown_1">
            <li><a href="">Product 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Product 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Product 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Product 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Product 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>        
    <li id="li_2"><a href="">SERVICES</a>
        <ul id="dropdown_2">
            <li><a href="">Service 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Service 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Service 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Service 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Service 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>        
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var slide_down_1 = function() {
    $('#dropdown_1').slideDown(300);
}

var slide_up_1 = function() {
    $('#dropdown_1').stop(true, true).slideUp(300);
}

$('#li_1').mouseenter(slide_down_1);
$('#li_1').mouseleave(slide_up_1);

var slide_down_2 = function() {
    $('#dropdown_2').slideDown(300);
}

var slide_up_2 = function() {
    $('#dropdown_2').stop(true, true).slideUp(300);
}

$('#li_2').mouseenter(slide_down_2);
$('#li_2').mouseleave(slide_up_2);


</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

using attribute selector with `^` which gets all the elements begining with the given string.. `hover()` shorthand for mouseenter() and mouseleave(), first argument is mouseenter function and the second is mouseleave function.

try this

```
$('li[id^="li"]').hover(function(){
   $(this).find('ul').slideDown();
},function(){
  $(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).slideUp();
});
```

this will work for all `<li>` tag.... instead of creating seperate function for each li.. call hover function for all `<li>` and use `$(this)` reference..

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/ZgAsP/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) which does both movements up and down

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#menu > li:has(ul)').hover(function(){
   $(this).find('ul').slideDown();
},function(){
  $(this).find('ul').slideUp();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZUmQW/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can reduce the lines of code if you understand the selectors properly.

```
$('li:has(ul)').mouseenter(function(){
   $('ul', this).slideDown(300);
}).mouseleave(function(){
   $('ul', this).stop(true, true).slideUp(300);
});
```

as you can see, I only selected the `li's` that have `ul` and then used `this` operator to further find `ul` inside that `li`

Comment: Thank you Umair. I also wanted to know which section of the book I need to study for this. The way you arranged your code is very understandable

Comment: Glad to help you. I am not sure which book you are talking about. BTW, I studied this all on StackOverFlow.

Comment: Wow, that's amazing. I just happened to bump to this site on the site on the net and just fell in love with the concept. It is my aim to connect and share ideas with the guys out there. Hope we connect more here...